# Read view field value in VBO action

Tags: 8, views

I have a view grid that has custom actions to perform based on selected grid row. To read the view fields from the grid dpm-ed the below command:

`dpm($this->view->result);`

The above command returns:

[image]

I am trying to specifically read the "field_comment_id_comment_field_data_nid" and I get null every time:

```
 dpm($this->view->result[0]->field_comment_id_comment_field_data_nid);
```

Update: I modified the dpm and I see the value correctly. Unsure of how to loop through the result array. still trying.

Comment: `ResultRow` doesn’t have a `get` method. The output says `field_comment_id_comment_field_data_nid` is a public property of the object so you can access it directly

Comment: I tried the below code: dpm($this->view->result->field_comment_id_comment_field_data_nid->Value) to read the value directly and I get null

Comment: You need to pay a bit more attention to the debug output - `$this->view->result` is an array

Comment: can i get some more help? I'm still seeing null on my end :( newbie here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Below solution works:

```
foreach($this->view->result as $result)
  dpm($result->field_comment_id_comment_field_data_nid);
}
```

thanks @clive for pointing on the array thing.